# why does my program quit and not run forever

Tags: python, node.js, websocket

I have a [websocket client code](https://github.com/liris/websocket-client) copied.. It works, except that it quits after print Hello 1..Hello 2 and Hello 3 and then it quits. I would assume run_forever meant that it will run forever, so why does it quit? How do I keep the program keep waiting on a websocket message?

```
import thread
import pdb
import websocket
import time
import requests

def on_message(ws, message):
    print message

def on_error(ws, error):
    print error

def on_close(ws):
    print "### closed ###"

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            ws.send("Hello %d" % i)
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print "thread terminating..."
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/"

    client = requests.session()

    EMAIL = "u234234"
    PASSWORD = "t234ri3234221"

    login_data = dict(username=EMAIL, password=PASSWORD)
    r = client.post(URL, data=login_data, headers=dict(Referer=URL))

    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost:8080/",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close,
        )
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: The source explains that it runs as long as the socket is available

Answer (score 1):

I can't claim to know very much about using websockets in python, but in general when you close a socket you close the associated connection as well. Thus, to keep the connection open, I think you might want to try removing the ws.close() line from your on_open function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I expect the thread.start_new_thread(run, ()) to kick off another run.. no?